# Jhipster microservices cause conflict on port 9300 of Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, microservices, jhipster

Elasticsearch works with ports 9200 and 9300, but if I start a JHipster micro-service configured to work with Elasticsearch before starting the Elasticsearch service Elasticsearch fails because something in the JHipster service starts at port 9300.
I checked this situation by running the `netstat -a` command in Windows CMD.

If Elasticsearch uses port 9300 and the microservice will use Elasticsearch, why is the microservice occupying port 9300?

Need to change anything else for the service to use Elasticsearch in dev mode?

Comment: If Elasticsearch is not started when the app is started in `dev`, it will launch an embedded Elasticsearch instance, which probably uses 9300. https://www.jhipster.tech/using-elasticsearch/

Answer (score 0):

You can run elasticsearch on different ports than the default one. To do so add/update in `elasticsearch.yml` file the following:

```
http.port: 9201
transport.port: 9301
```